# Creating context for JSON-LD

Tags: json-ld, linked-data

As a simple exercise I wanted to take some test-data from a little app I had which produced a user record in JSON and turn it into JSON-LD, testing on JSON-LD.org's playground gives some help, but I don't know if I'm doing it right.

The original is:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 1
        "Username": "Dave",
        "Colour":"green“
    }
]
```

So I have a person, who has a username, an ID and an associated colour.

What I've got so far is:

```
{  
  "@context": {    
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",
    "Colour": {
      "@id": "http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Colour",
      "@type": "http://schema.org/Text",
      "@language": "en"
    }
  },
  "@type": "http://schema.org/Person",     
  "@Id": "http://example.com/player/1",
  "sameAs" : "https://www.facebook.com/DaveAlger",
  "Id": 1,
  "name": "David Alger",
  "Username": "Dave",  
  "Colour": "green" 
}
```

So I'm declaring it's a @type of person, and given a URI @id.

I'm also using the "sameAs" idea, which I saw on a blog-post once, but am unclear if it is just supported right off.

Then I've tried to create a @context. Here that I've added a name and given that a reference. I've tried to create something for "colour" too. I'm not sure if pointing to a DBpedia reference about "colour" and specifying a @type and @language is good, or not.

I suppose the final thing is "username", but that feels so deeply internal to a site that it doesn't make sense to "Link" it at all.

I'm aware this data is perhaps not even worth linking, this is very much a learning exercise for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think that [`http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Colour`](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Colour) should be used like that. It’s a class, not a property. The property that has `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Colour` as range is [`http://dbpedia.org/ontology/colour`](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/colour). (That said, I’m not sure if your really intend that the person should have a colour, instead of something related to this person.)

If you want to provide the language of the colour strings, you should not specify the datatype, `@language` is sufficient (if a value is typed, it can’t have a language anymore; by using `@language`, it’s implied that the value is a string).

You are using `@Id` for specifying the node’s URI, but it must be `@id`.

The properties `sameAs`, `Id` and `Username` are not defined in your `@context`.

- If you intend to use [Schema.org’s `sameAs` property](http://schema.org/sameAs), you could define it similar to what you did with `name`, but you should specify that the value is a URI:

  ```
  "sameAs": {
    "@id": "http://schema.org/sameAs",
    "@type": "@id"
  },
  ```
- For `Username`, you could use [FOAF’s `nick` property](http://xmlns.com/foaf/spec/#term_nick), or maybe [Schema.org’s `alternateName` property](http://schema.org/alternateName).
- No idea which property you could use for `Id` (depends on your case if this is useful for others at all, or if this is only relevant for your internal system).

Comment: Some really good and helpful points here I think. 

Interesting to see the difference between a class and property, that helps. It also brings something else into focus: this object I'm specifying is a "player record", and the player has a "colour" in a game and that player is also a person (which can be linked to the person on Facebook), but is it wrong then to declare the object type as person? Should there be a more subtle link? Of the sort that this player, who has a username is also the person with the name and related same as?

Comment: @DaveAlger: That’s a good question, but I guess it’s too complex for answering it in a comment (and it’s more healthy for the site to have this in an actual answer post which can be down-voted/edited), and I’m sure there are different opinions about it.